# How to generate Unique ID without form submission in php ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i fill up 4 field(Name,Phone,Course,Center) in my form. 5th field is "roll". when i fill up 4 field, then how to generate roll without form submission,
i want to generate roll like that
My 4 field text are below
Name-Jack,Phone-1234567890,Course-Computer,Center-010
after fill up this field then generate roll and print 5th field without form submission
Roll-Jac890Com10

Comment: Jac890Com10 still wont be an unique id

Comment: Please show your code.

Answer (score 0):

You could attach an `onchange` event to your inputs.

```
<form method="post" action="">
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" onchange="my_validate_func()">
<input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" onchange="my_validate_func()">
<input type="text" name="course" id="course" onchange="my_validate_func()">
<input type="text" name="center" id="center" onchange="my_validate_func()">
<input type="text" name="roll" id="roll">
<button type="submit">Submit</button>
```

```
function my_validate_func (){ 
   if($('#name').val()!="" && $('#phone').val()!="" && $('#course').val()!="" && $('#center').val()!=""){
       $.ajax({
         url:'your_url',
         success: function(response){
            $('#roll').val(response.roll_num);
         }
       });
   }
}
```

Comment: In your_url i write submit.php page. What can i write in submit.php page

Comment: You need to put your logic there to generate roll number and send it back as response